# Vuejs returning with { ...}

Tags: javascript, vue.js, return

Iam currently working with a project where project is almost partially completed. So I just saw a some weired code whihc I havent seen before and tried to find it via google and couldnt find anythig.

This is the code

```
methods:  {

getMap() {
   let A = this.$store.getters['MAP']
   let B = this.$store.getters['MAP2']

   return { ...A, ...B}
 }

}
```

What I really wants to know is

> return { ...A, ...B}

what does it means ? any reference or any clarification please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's javascript [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). What it does is merge two objects by keys, similar to `Object.assign`. For instance, in the following example, keys from A and B are merged into the final object with values from the latter object taking precedence.

```js
const A = { a: 3, b: 4 }
const B = { c: 5, d: 7, a: 4 }

console.log({ ...A, ...B })
```

In your case, `getMap` return a combined object with key value pairs from `Map` and `Map2` merged.